# Long notes without hardware

Tags: guitar, recording, logic-pro

I really want to record a lick which is actually an arpeggiated chord where each next note is played over previous while all of those notes remain ringing. I don’t have any hardware like sustain or volume pedals. Just a sound recording device and Logic Pro X. How can achieve this? Any plugin? Or audio samples editing (changing gain, fade out of a range of samples in audio file).

I’m asking about implementation, not theory. You can listen to song “Marathon” by Rush, where guitar solo starts (timecode: 2:59), if you please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are effects for DSPs that will provide either a Sustain effect, or as in the Rush example, it's a simple delay with the wet balance attack slowed considerably to lose the pick sound.

For the slow attack, I would really use a volume pedal, but you can program it into most DSPs.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of sound is often written for classical guitar playing, but is written incorrectly, and looks like each note should be stopped before the next is played, rather than holding down the whole chordful of notes. It needs looking at carefully, and translating into something that sounds good. But if played *exactly* as writ, sounds awful.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but: 1) I’m not playing classical guitar, as I orient on Rush (which is a rock band with a strong deviation from classical patterns). 2) I’m asking about implementation, not theory. You can listen to song “Marathon” by Rush, where guitar solo starts (timecode: 2:59), if you please.